# On the formulation of the linear assignment problem

Tags: algorithm, math, operations-research

I'm looking at the standard definition of the assignment problem as defined [here](http://www.assignmentproblems.com/linearAP.htm)

My question is to do with the two constraints (latex notation follows):

```
\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{ij}) = 1 for all i = 1, ... , n
\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{ij}) = 1 for all j = 1, ... , n
```

Specifically, why the second constraint required? Doesn't the first already cover all pairs of x_{ij}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the matrix `x_ij` with the `i` ranging over the rows, and `j` ranging over the columns.

The first equation says that for each `i` (that is, for each row!) the sum of values in that row equals 1.

The second equations says thta for each `j` (that is, for each column!) the sum of values in that column equals 1.

Comment: I understand what it says. It just seems redundant. If I already have an exactly one assignment for each row then it follows there is an equivalent assignment for each column. Why the repetition?

Comment: Ah, I see! because otherwise I could have the same row index assigned to more than one column! 

Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not sure I follow your last statement. Imagine a 2x2 matrix with 1's in the first column, and 0's everywhere else. Each row would sum to 1, but the first column sum to 2. This demonstrates that summing over rows and summing over columns are different things.

Comment: Yup, I see it. Thanks again. 
I was just pointing out that without the second constraint it would be possible to make an assignment like x_{1,2} and x_{1,5} where 2 and 5 are columns in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

No. Given that all the entries in `X` are `0` or `1`, one constraint says 'there is exactly one `1` in each *column*' - the other says 'there is exactly one `1` in each *row*' (I always forget which way round matrix subscripts conventionally go). These statements have independent truth values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not even remotely a programming problem. But I'll answer it anyway.

The first is a sum over j, for EACH value of i. The second is a sum over i, for EACH value of j.

So essentially, one of these constraint sets requires that the sum across the rows of the matrix x_{i,j} matrix must be unity. The other constraint is a requirement that the sum down the columns of that matrix must be unity.

(edit) It seems that we are still not being clear here. Consider the matrix

```
[0 1]
[0 1]
```

One must agree that the sum across the rows of this matrix is 1 for each row. However, when you form the sum of the elements of the first column, it is zero, and the sum of the elements in the second column, we find 2.

Now, consider a different matrix.

```
[0 1]
[1 0]
```

See that here, the sum over the rows or down the columns is always 1.